# python dynamic dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

im creating a function that will handle xml data, the data can vary but the structure is the same :

events ( list like )
   event 
      info
         additional info

the function needs to create a dictionary that contains a mapping in which if the data being looped is not 0 then the data needs to be mapped in a dictionary, heres my solution:

```
def parse_items(self, xml):
            """ Builds a dynamic dictionary tree wich holds each event in a dictionary
               that can be accessed by number of event """
            parsed_items = {}
            parsed_item = {}
            sub_info = {}
            for num, item in enumerate(xml):
                for tag in item:
                    if len(tag) != 0:
                        for info in tag:
                            sub_info[info.tag] = info.text
                        parsed_item[tag.tag] = sub_info
                        # Need to flush the dictionary else it will repeat info
                        sub_info = {}
                    else:
                        parsed_item[tag.tag] = tag.text
                parsed_items[num] = parsed_item
                # Need to flush the dictionary else it will repeat info
                parsed_item = {}
            return parsed_items
```

my question is, is there a way to make this dynamically without having to make for loops for every level of data ?

Comment: i thought about it, but i want all data to be mapped for quick access, so i only want to use dictionaries

Comment: In the latest versions of Python, there are dict comprehensions too: `sub_info = {i.tag: i.text for i in tag}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Reposting as an answer, because the questioner intends to use the idea)

In the latest versions of Python, there are dict comprehensions as well as list comprehensions. Like this:

```
sub_info = {i.tag: i.text for i in tag}
```

Comment: For older python versions: `dict(((i.tag, i.text) for i in tag))`